# DomPDF not working in Zend Framework 1.12.0 An input file is required (i.e. input_file _GET variable)

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, dompdf

DomPDF throws the following error, using Zend Framework 1.12.0.

```
Error
An input file is required (i.e. input_file _GET variable).
```

However, it works fine using Zend 1.7.0.

Here is the way I've included it in the controller

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
```

And this is how I instantiate Zend Loader Autoloader in my Bootstrap file

```
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

I believe it may be due to autoloading DOMPDF. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of dompdf? The error looks like what you'd get if dompdf.php was run without input. This could happen if the ZF autoloader was used instead of the dompdf one (since dompdf doesn't follow the ZF file naming convention). 0.6.0 has a much improved autoloader, though I don't have any experience with ZF.

Comment: I'm using dompdf version 0.5.2, since 0.6.0 is still in beta.

Comment: Though 0.6.0 is still in beta we definitely recommend it. It's as stable as 0.5.2 and has many improvements.